# Postgres detach partition and cascade remove all related rows

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    site character varying(4) NOT NULL,
    order character varying(8) NOT NULL,
    expires_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pick_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, expires_on)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (expires_on);
```

I am using PSQL-14.

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    order_id bigint,
    updated_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    expires_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT order_fk FOREIGN KEY (expires_on, order_id)
        REFERENCES order (expires_on, id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        NOT VALID
)
```

I am trying to solve here is on detachment of a partition, I want the corresponding FK records to also be cleared out. In the ideal world, I'd like to partition all of the tables based on the order id according to its expires_on date.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want a composite primary key? And how many records per partition do you expect?

Comment: Hi, the composite key seems to be enforced by postgres and won't let me partition without it.

PRIMARY KEY constraint on table "order" lacks column "expires_on" which is part of the partition key.unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns 

I am expecting the partitions to be in the tens of thousands.

Comment: When your primary key exists of (id, expires_on), you must reference to this combination as well. Could you share the DDL for this table and its foreign key? (by the way, "order" is a terrible name, it's reserved word: ORDER BY)

Comment: Updated. TY. One of the main things I am trying to solve here is on detachment of a partition, I want the corresponding FK records to also be cleared out.

Comment: You just edited the question with an SQL statement that shows the correct way to create the foreign key, and you have changed the question. Then you should change the question completely, that is, remove the error message. A better title could also help. Most important, describe your new problem in more detail. I for one don't understand it. General tip: if you want to detach partitions on the referenced table, that won't work. Don't define foreign keys referencing a partitioned table if you want to do that.

Comment: Hi Laurenz. I am not trying to be difficult, I wasn't sure how to ask the right question. I have the primary composite key setup for successful partitioning on the primary (order) table. When I detach that partition, I want all related data to be removed as well. My existing design prior to partitions was using the order PK as the FK for the customer table, but because of the composite PK I could no longer do this. Hence the confusion. I have updated the title as per your recommendation.

Comment: Is the only way to go, to partition each related table and maintain an expires_on datetime across all tables?

Comment: Why don’t you just truncate the tables? And why this need for partitioning? How many records do you expect?

Comment: Hi, I plan to use AWS and need to archive data fairly regularly to keep the data down. AWS recommend using pg_partman and partitioning for easy detach and drop of data. Probably something in the region on 15k rows per day.

Comment: AWS RDS* which is essentially psql